# Working with large amount of Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am creating web portal in asp.net 4.0  where i have to send http web request to 3rd party server and getting large volume of resultset which is to be a user specific. My problem is,where do i store these data temporally?

Is there a better way to store large results set temporarily?

Response which we are getting from http webrequest is specific to different users (request basis) and we must keep the data until user complete shopping or booking so do not know how long we keep the data.

adding more :

We were thhinking to use session object , but due to large volume of data, we can not use it as it will consume server memory.

Second option, we can use sql relational database, but website is consuming data from httpweb response so we do not have control the 3rd party service.

Comment: Does your server code need to use this data on subsequent requests?

Comment: also, how "fresh" does the data in the portal need to be? Is it mostly static/unfrequently changed?

Comment: What are you doing with that data?  How long do you need to hold onto it for?  Is it even possible to store it in memory for the duration of the request, or is even that not feasible?

Comment: Large is a relative term, how large is large? 8 inches? :D Anyways, why don't you just store the data in a DB and resync your store with the 3rd party DB at some predetermined point?

Comment: Response which we are getting from http webrequest is specific to different users (request basis) and we must keep the data until user complete shopping or booking so do not know how long we keep the data.

Answer (score 1):

`Session` is typically stored in server memory and thus not a great place to store large amounts of data. I would suggest a SQL table but all things are relative... How large is this data? If you have more than a single web server, session state has likely been moved to SQL so better to go there directly.

Comment: We have only one server and due to data size is approx 100MB to 500MB but not sure because its totally depends on the httpwebresponse. If we use sql relative table, will that affect the performance?

Comment: Also i need to hold data for next 30 mins.

Comment: SQL on a reasonable server is likely fast enough. 500 MB per user in Session is a lot. I would give SQL a try. You can always schedule a job to delete used SQL data after your 30 minutes or use the global.asax `Session_End` event to clean up your SQL data.